# MySQL - Insert takes more time

Tags: mysql

The MySQL 5.6.40 is running with the load of 2.4% CPU, but an insert query took 3 secs. Here is the slow query log,

```
# Time: 190216 2:15:06
# Query_time: 3.187892 Lock_time: 3.187890 Rows_sent: 0 Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1550283306;
INSERT INTO worker_job(tenant, type, name, meta, user, status) VALUES('store', 'SWAP', '37943', '37943', 'cf82c458-9eea-4265-967d-51fda645f52f', 'PENDING');
```

Here is table schema,

```
CREATE TABLE `worker_job` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tenant` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `meta` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('PENDING','IN_PROGRESS','FAILED','COMPLETED','CANCELED','WIP') DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_on` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `message` varchar(1024) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `idx_job` (`tenant`,`type`,`name`),
  KEY `idx_wj_s` (`status`)
);
```

Explain output,

```
mysql> explain INSERT INTO worker_job(tenant, type, name, meta, user, status) VALUES('store', 'SWAP', '37943', '37943', 'cf82c458-9eea-4265-967d-51fda645f52f', 'PENDING');
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | No tables used |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------+
```

Any other factor which is affecting this write?

Comment: The delay could be due to other situational factors. Did you try re-running the query? Was a similar trend in delay encountered again?

Comment: Most likely the table or index was locked by another query. `INSERT` by itself is very simple, so if it takes a while it's because of something else delaying it.

Comment: Slow query log shows insert to this table frequently. Even though only 10 inserts per minute and table has 1.6m rows. Is it possible to find which query is blocking by any setting in MySQL?

Comment: Are you using `innoDB` for the storage engine? If your table is big the unique index `idx_job` can also affect performance since it needs to make sure the value been inserted is unique.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. The problem is due to huge size of the table (2m rows) and indexes and insertions & updation happening in the table. I have moved the completed items to history table and not facing lag in insert